# Keyboard Shortcuts for Multi-Touch Gestures

Tags: keyboard, mouse, gesture

I would like to customize buttons of my mouse to support some [multi-touch mouse gestures](https://support.apple.com/en-us/102482).

Are there a list of keyboard shortcuts for the gestures (for the ones that are possible to map)?